# Llist installed packages with their repository name, version, and architecture using zypper

Tags: options, suse, zypper

`zypper se -i` shows installed packages, but unlike `zypper pa` the repo, arch, and version information is missing. Is there a command option that shows these bits?

Answer (score 1):

The man page of zypper shows you many options, one of them is `-s` and shows more details:

```
control01:~ # zypper se -si openssl
Repository-Daten werden geladen...
Installierte Pakete werden gelesen...

S | Name              | Type  | Version             | Arch   | Repository
--+-------------------+-------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------
i | libopenssl1_1     | Paket | 1.1.1d-lp152.7.27.1 | x86_64 | openSUSE-Leap-15.2-Updates for x86_64
i | openssl           | Paket | 1.1.1d-lp152.1.1    | noarch | openSUSE-Leap-15.2-Pool for x86_64
i | openssl-1_1       | Paket | 1.1.1d-lp152.7.27.1 | x86_64 | openSUSE-Leap-15.2-Updates for x86_64
i | python3-pyOpenSSL | Paket | 17.5.0-lp152.7.3.1  | noarch | openSUSE-Leap-15.2-Updates for x86_64
```